# How do I return records based on which records only exist during a certain time period?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've got a table of invoices and customer codes. I'd like to pull only the customers that have not done any business with us since 2009.

My regular select statement is simple

```
SELECT INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE FROM INVOICES

WHERE INVOICES.ORDER_DATE <= '01-01-2010'
```

But, this statement also pulls customer codes of customers who have done business before and after 2010. I want only those customers that have not done business before 2010. It seems so simple, but I can't grasp how to do this and my google searches only bring up how to do a range of dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your latest comment is correct, but the first where clause is redundant - the below will work :

```
SELECT INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE FROM INVOICE
WHERE INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE NOT IN (SELECT INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE FROM INVOICE WHERE INVOICE.ORDER_DATE >= '01-01-2010')
```

The invoice table has all your customers. You first select all those customers who have done business since 2009 (in the subquery). Then you select all remaining customers. This can also be accomplished by the following, probably-easier-to-understand code :

```
SELECT INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE FROM INVOICE
EXCEPT
SELECT INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE FROM INVOICE WHERE INVOICE.ORDER_DATE >= '01-01-2010'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe I have figured it out. I'll have to do some more checking to be sure.

```
SELECT INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE FROM INVOICE

WHERE INVOICE.ORDER_DATE < '01-01-2010'
AND INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE NOT IN (SELECT INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE FROM INVOICE WHERE INVOICE.ORDER_DATE >= '01-01-2010')
```

Comment: Using NOT EXISTS () would be better than NOT IN().

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like:

```
; with cc as (
    Select Distinct
           INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE
    From   Invoice
    Where  INVOICE.ORDER_DATE >= '01-01-2010'
)
Select INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE
From   INVOICE
Where  INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CODE not in (select * from cc)
```